# Sonarqube incorrectly reports "Unexpected missing generic font family"

Tags: css, sonarqube, sonarcloud

Sonarqube is showing this bug "Unexpected missing generic font family" even though this **sans-serif** generic font family is included in the font-family set. Is this a false positive from Sonarcloud? Or are there any real bug in this CSS code snippet.
[image]

This is the code snippet of the font-family CSS block.

```css
body {
    line-height: 1;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Microsoft Sans Serif", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Verdana", "Sans-serif", "trebuchet ms" !important;

}
```

Comment: try removing quotes around sans-serif

Answer (score 3):

I had the same bug with:

```
font-family: "MyCoolFont, sans-serif";
```

And fix it by removing the quotes (W3C recommends using quotes only when the names of the font families have spaces, digits or punctuation characters):

```
font-family: MyCoolFont, sans-serif;
```

In your case I would also write *Sans-serif* in lower case -> *sans-serif*. Usually the generic family font is the last one, but I guess is not a requirement; although if the bug persists you could try to add another generic font at the end of the line ([W3C generic fonts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families)).